# How to change buddypress default button name "Add Friend" to Interest

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

How to change buddypress default  button name "Add Friend"  to Interest  how to change default name in wordpress, buddypress  from which script i can change the name.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with

```
add_filter( 'bp_get_add_friend_button', 'change_add_friend_button' );
function change_add_friend_button($button){
    $button['link_text'] = __( 'Make Friend', 'buddypress' );
    return $button;
}
```

Comment: this change the whole button text, the add friend and remove friend man! tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit the file in this path:
 wp-content/plugins/buddypress/buddypress.pot

Here you can create your own custom messages and labels without doing a full language translation.

I hope this help.